# Is it secure to connect remotly to Mysql using shell?

Tags: linux, shell, security, mysql

I have created a shell script to connect to a DB and do some queries:

```
#/!bin/bash
...
...
mysql -h remote -u root --password='pw' MatchingDB 
some SQL queries
```

My question is : Is this connection considered as Secured connection, Can any attacker sniff any query I send to the remote DB or maybe change the queries I have sent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but don't provide the password on the command line. It will prompt for the password when you omit it form the command line switches.

#### Example

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 227743
Server version: 5.0.95 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

#### Handling your password securely

Take a look at the recommendations from the MySQL documentation. The page titled: [6.1.2.1 End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-security-user.html) highlights the various methods and discusses the pluses/minuses of each.

Of the options discusses you'll likely want to use an options file.

*excerpt*

> Store your password in an option file. For example, on Unix, you can list your password in the [client] section of the .my.cnf file in your home directory:
>
> ```
>    [client]
>    password=your_pass
> ```
>
> To keep the password safe, the file should not be accessible to anyone but yourself. To ensure this, set the file access mode to 400 or 600. For example:
>
> ```
>    shell> chmod 600 .my.cnf
>
>    shell> mysql --defaults-file=/home/francis/mysql-opts
> ```

All the methods discusses have their issues from a security perspective, but this is probably the least risky, assuming the directory you're running these on is isolated from others with privileged access.

#### Using vaults

If the work you'll be doing is what I would term "supporting production" installations then using password vaults is really the appropriate mechanism here. You can read more about them in this MySQL articled titled: [5.3.6 The Password Storage Vault](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-vault.html).

Under Linux, GNOME specifically, you'd be using the GNOME `gnome-keyring` daemon.

#### References

- [save mysql logins](https://superuser.com/questions/233645/save-mysql-logins)

Comment: how can I login to the DB without provide the password to the command line @slm

Comment: @Networker - see updates

Comment: but I want to provide the password using the shell script, I don't want to write it mannually every time I run the script – @slm

Comment: @slm, I use the first approach that you have discussed :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably enable the SSL support for the connection.

To check whether a `mysqld` server supports `SSL`, examine the value of the `have_ssl` system variable,

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_ssl      | YES   |
+---------------+-------+
```

If the value is **YES**, the server supports **SSL** connections. If the value is **DISABLED**, the server is **capable** of supporting SSL connections but was not started with the appropriate `--ssl-xxx` options to enable them to be used.

Probably, check from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-ssl-connections.html) on how to setup the mysql server with SSL support.